# display a number of entries for a specific uid in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to display a number of entries for a specific uid.

this is my function but it can not display any value

```
function anscount()
{
    global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'pte_quiz';
                $sql = "SELECT Count(*) AS count FROM $table_name WHERE uid =1";
                    echo "Count Number: ";
}
add_action('init','anscount');
```

Comment: you need to run $sql first and then need to print..!

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/63964/142349

Answer (score 1):

try this way brother :

```
function anscount()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'pte_quiz';
    $sql = "SELECT Count(*) AS count FROM $table_name WHERE uid =1";
    $myrow = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    if (isset($myrow[0]) && isset($myrow[0]->count)) {
        echo "Count Number: ".$myrow[0]->count;
    }
}
add_action('init','anscount');
```